# Grab the page which is redirecting

Tags: php

I am trying to grab a file .pdf from a server. There is a hyperlink at the page, by clicking that link it goes to a page, it checks for some privileges, then it redirects to another page which shows the content of the .pdf within an Iframe.

lets say beginning url is http://site.com/docs/1.pdf
on click it goes to another page, then another one and it comes whth the last page 
http://site.com/viewer/pdfs/1.pdf
the last page shows the pdf content within an Iframe.

I realized that the software IDM (Internet download manager) can follow the redirections and download the file by clicking the first link.

I was wondering if there is an algorithm or library or class or hint that I can figure out how to do that in PHP scripting.

by the way, once I wrote a code to read the header of the page and I could redirect to the second page, but I want to know if there is a general algorithm for this or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are doing the HTTP stuff manually, check for `30x` statuscodes and the `Location` header.

However, you could simply use CURL and set `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`.

Comment: +1, there is no general algorithm because you will have to parse a HTML page anyway to get the iframe `href`. But CURL is a good starting point for following `Location` headers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just like ThiefMaster said, you could look for the `Location` header.
Have a look here, maybe this can be a help to you:
http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/1214 This function retrieves file size of a remote file, why don't you try to change it slightly so that it gets the final URL?